# Image not in span-class after giving it an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the following code with bootstrap to create a banner directly on top of my page. Problem is, the image is at the the very left corner of my page. As soon as I delete the id='banner' flag, the image starts at the correct point just like the rest of my page. Is it because it's not treated as an bootstrap-span-element anymore? I'm sure there is an easy solution. Thanks for help.

```
  <body>
    <div class="container" id="banner">
      <div class="row">
        <!--span>fdsssssssssssssssssssss</span-->
        <img src="images/fcrlogo.png" max-width="100%" max-height="100%" class="span1">

        <!-- h1> Your banner </h1 -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What `CSS` is applied to the `#banner` selector? You can see that from the Dev Console.

Comment: `spanN` elements are from BS 2 I think, by the way - consider upgrading to v3!

Comment: Try showing us which styles is affecting the the banner id in your css. The styles in this id are the ones most probably causing the problem.

Comment: I made a override for the #banner selector:
`#banner {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1515B5;
}`

because the banner should take the width of the hole page. Is there a different solution?

Comment: Is there a way to delete the #banner selector just for the image?